# how to track user experience windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, tracking, c#-5.0

I have to develop an application that track user experience. When he used my application? how much he spent time using it ? so is there thread or attributes that i could use them to know if my application is running, is opened or is closed ?

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. Have fun working on it and let us know how it goes and if you run into any specific problems or issues. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write all your own code to track usage with timers etc., to track events when it is started and when it shutdown etc.. Then write a lot more code to somehow store that data for you to access.

Or you can use one of many analytic tools that are available to really reduce your development time and stress of figuring all this out.

[Google Analytics for Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/)

[Article from Nokia on how to use Flurry Analytics](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_add_Flurry_Analytics_to_your_Windows_Phone_app)

[PreEmptive also used to make one for Windows Phone](http://www.preemptive.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an analytics solution like Google Analytics for tracking app usage. You can take a look at [this article](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http://geeks.ms/blogs/jyeray/archive/2013/07/15/windows-phone-8-a-241-adir-google-analytics-a-nuestras-aplicaciones.aspx) i wrote on my blog (original in spanish, automatic translated with microsoft translator).

Hope this helps you.